# overlaying multiple regression lines R

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

How can I plot a regression fit for the variable "gre" and "rank" separately on the same graph?

```
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")


m1 = glm(admit ~ gre + rank, family=binomial, data=mydata)

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=gre + rank,y=admit))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method='glm',method.args=list(family="binomial"),se=TRUE)
```

Comment: It looks like you want what I would call an added variable plot (aka partial regression plot).  In that case, you'll need to make the predictions for one variable with the other fixed to some value (usually mean or median) and then plot those predictions with `geom_line()`.  I think I show a basic of example of this from an lme object in this section of my "plot fitted lines" blog post [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/11/16/plot-fitted-lines/#plotting-fitted-lines-from-an-lme-object).

Comment: That's pretty much what I need. I just do not know what you mean by fixing the others. I starting to believe that the plot will not be easily readable given the differences in x axis values/ranges for each predictor variable. I was hoping for a simpler way of combining this. Does the original plot make sense ? Is it statistically acceptable ?

Comment: To be honest, trying to get regression lines from two different x variables on the same plot doesn't make a bunch of sense to me unless the variables take on the same values/range.  Maybe use facets or make separate plots and stack together (e.g., use package **patchwork**)?

Comment: I'm glad we agree. I'm aware of facets, just obsessed with overlays for some unknown reason :). Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Achilles Try `car::avPlots(m1)`.